# Angular 8 - Problema com acentos html

Tags: html, angular

Eu tenho um vetor no meu componente que está acentuado com código html.

```
text=[ 'DRENAGEM AUT&Oacute;GENA','BAG SQUEEZING','RESPIRA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O DIAFRAGM&Aacute;TICA','CAR','AFE','INSPIRA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O EM TEMPOS','FRENO LABIAL','INSPIRA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O SUSTENTADA', 'INCENTIVADOR A FLUXO', 'HUFFING', 'VIBRA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O','COMPRESS&Atilde;O-DESCOMPRESS&Atilde;O'];    

<div class="col-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 m-2 p-1" *ngFor="let t of text; let i = index"
  style="background-color: aliceblue">
  <div class="w-100 h-100">
    <app-card #card_1 number="{{ i + 1 }}" word="{{ t }}" [front]="!mestre" group="{{ groups[i] }}"><span
        class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Primary</span></app-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Quando eu faço um ngFor para mostrar todas as palavras {{ palavra }} ele não mostra a letra acentuada. Continua mostrando VIBRA &Ccedil ; &Atilde ;O

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Alguma solução simples pra resolver isso?

Answer (score 3):

O problema é você estar usando as entidades HTML em vez de texto puro pros acentos, o Angular vai tratar ele apenas como texto e não como HTML.

Se você tem controle sobre este texto então o mais fácil é alterar para ele ter acentos normais, se esta opção não for viável as alternativas são de fazer um binding com o innerHtml

```
<div [innerHtml]="palavra">
```

Ou usar um pipe para decodificar o texto

```ts
@Pipe({name: "decodeHtmlString"})
export class DecodeHtmlString implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string) {
        const tempElement = document.createElement("div");
        tempElement.innerHTML = value;
        return tempElement.innerText;
    }
}

{{palavra | decodeHtmlString}}
```

No caso deste pipe acho importante notar que ele remove qualquer tag HTML que existir no seu texto, se por exemplo for passado para ele o valor `&aacute;<script>alert("teste")</script>` o resultado vai ser `áalert("teste")`

Comment: Leandro, é provável que seu código venha a funcionar, mas não teria uma outra forma de rearranjar isto? Porque brother, isto ai tá criando um objeto/elemento no navegador, fazendo um "recurso técnico" e não está limpando o objeto.

Comment: Salvo que eu esteja errado e o objeto seja limpo no fim da função. Eu sugiro então pelo menos limpar o objeto pra evitar uma sobrecarga no navegador do cliente. Dependendo de onde e como ele usar isto, pode ser que venha gerar muuuuuiita cópia no navegador. A cada iteração do usuário com a página o Angular vai recarregar isto e gerar um objeto novo, sabe como é.

Comment: Não creio que exista um problema, fica pro navegador e eu diria que no geral o GC vai limpar isso assim que possível, estou vendo uma terceira alternativa que não usa isso e vou incluir na resposta assim que conseguir testar

Comment: Interessante, pesquisei a respeito e sim, o garbage collector do navegador se encarrega de limpar. Top seu código, a melhor resposta para o usuário até o momento. +1 por mim

Comment: Pelo que vi aqui a outra alternativa seria usar o método `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` do `DomSanitizer` para ele permitir que o HTML seja usado, porém ele não funciona com o `{{ bindings }}`, apenas com `[property]=binding` e não estou certo do seu funcionamento para incluir ele na resposta, pois ele me parece acabar funcionando apenas se usar como na primeira solução `[innerHtml]="binding | pipe"`, que neste caso não faz muito sentido. Se quiserem tem um [exemplo aqui](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b)

Comment: Olá, resolvi usando o [innerHtml] e funcinou. Vou deixar salvo a opção do pipe só por aprendizagem. Mas esse bind com o innerHtml foi show. Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Verifique se o seu código tem essa seguinte estrutura básica:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Ele deve possuir ao menos a tag `<meta charset="utf-8">` para que os acentos sejam aceitos! :)

Answer (score -2):

Insira no cabeçalho da sua página a tag meta charset e insira o valor "utf-8", pois essa tag é responsável por aceitar acentos, ç, e demais símbolos que pertencem a língua portuguesa. Desse modo o código inicial da página deverá ficar da seguinte forma:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
```